# How I use edit function from QtWidgets in my custom Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am developing a Custom Plugin on QGIS for my research project. I need to use edit function from QtWidgets on my python code. I have tried to import QtWidgets module but its get error.

```py
from qgis.core import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

fn = fn_Intersection

layer = QgsVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
pv = layer.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('A', QVariant.Double)])

layer.updateFields()

expression1 = QgsExpression('$Area/1000000')

context = QgsExpressionContext()

context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['A'] = expression1.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

`fn_Intersection` is a file directory I have define

```
Error:

    File "C:\Users/me/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\sump\Sump.py", line 535, in Run_clicked
              with edit(layer):
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py", line 38, in __enter__
              assert self.layer.startEditing()
             AssertionError
```

Comment: You are getting this error because your `layer` object is invalid. It is invalid because, by your own admission, you are attempting to create a `QgsVectorLayer`, by passing a path to a file directory instead of a path to an actual valid vector data source e.g. a shapefile or geopackage. Neither the error nor the `with edit(layer)` statement have anything to do with importing the QtWidgets module.